# Shader based intersection mask

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to create a material that would allow me to create a mask on a plane based on intersections between the plane and other geometries.

Illustration:
[image]
I need to get from this

[image]
To this.

Is there any way to do this using only shader nodes, alternatively by code in python? I am trying not to use boolean operations as they are computationaly heavy for larger scenes and often fail. If not can you suggest the best approach to achieve this effect?

Comment: Would Dynamic Paint or Geometry Nodes be acceptable? If not, OSL?

Comment: Anything is accaptable as long as I can dynamically recalculate the mask whenever objects move without causing lags and while I can use it both in cycles and eevee. Do you have any ideas?